# UnknownHostException SmbFile while accessing network drive

Tags: java, gradle

I have shared one drive through windows. Both PC are connected through LAN cable and able to access through windows explorer.

But same path is not being accessed using SmbFile in Java. I have written following lines to access all files and folders of that network path.

```
SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile("smb://DESKTOP-SERVER/");
SmbFile[] smbFiles = smbFile.listFiles();
```

Error it throws is "UnknownHostException" and "Failed to connect to server".

I am using gradle project in vs code. What wrong am I doing here.

Comment: Are you referring to [Samba](https://www.samba.org/) software?

Comment: I am not using that software.

Comment: All I needed was to get files and folders which are on network.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must use back-slash: `smb://DESKTOP-SERVER/`.

And you have to remember about authentication:

```
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthenticator(user, pass);
SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(path, auth);
```

Comment: Tried backslash as well. Same error. For authentication,currently there isn't any. So I also tried NtlmPasswordAuthentication.ANONYMOUS. but that also isn't working.

Comment: There is similar question I just found.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26916902/9263418. But that uses username password. My PC doesn't need password (open book. You know :)). So

Comment: Is your second PC is also with Windows, what versions? Try to connect using ip-address.

Comment: Yes. Both windows 10. Tried ip address. Same error.